# How to dynamically Filter an IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, model-binding

I need to build a dynamic query using LINQ to filter elements of an `IEnumerable` -which is used as the `SelectMethod` on a `Repeater` control- to display the correct data from my entity model. I am really not sure where to start.

vb or c# is fine, and I prefer the method-based syntax of LINQ opposed to query-expression syntax, but whatever gets the job done...

**HTML**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="pList" runat="server" ItemType="rsDataAccess.Product" SelectMethod="GetProducts">
  <ItemTemplate>
     ...
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Bad example of what I want to accomplish**

```
Public Function GetProducts() As IEnumerable(Of Product)

  Dim products As Product =
  repo.Product.Where(Function(r) r.Status = "Open")

  Dim query As String = ""

  If option1 = True Then
    query += "Where(function(r) r.Price > 100)"
  End If

  If option2 = True Then
    query += "Where(function(r) r.Zip = 63039 "
  End If

  products += query

  Return products
End Function
```

The [objectContext.CreateQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339670%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the only function (that I know of) that's even remotely close to providing the functionality that I need, but my guess is that there is a better approach. So please, tell me what that better approach is.

I know that I could just return the IEnumerable inside of the if statements, but that is not what I am looking for.

```
If option1 = True Then
  Return repo.Products.Where(Function(r) r.Price > 100)
End If

If option2 = True Then
  Return repo.Products.Where(Function(r) r.Zip = 63039)
End If
```

Comment: May I understand you are looking for a way to do dynamic where in linq?

Comment: @PandaZhang Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not optimized, but should do the job:

```
Public Function GetProducts() As IEnumerable(Of Product)

   Dim products As IEnumerable(Of Product) =
     repo.Product.Where(Function(r) r.Status = "Open")

   If option1 Then
       products = products.Concat(repo.Product.Where(function(r) r.Price > 100))
   End If

   If option2 Then
       products = products.Concat(repo.Product.Where(function(r) r.Zip = 63039))
   End If

   Return products.Distinct()
End Function
```

Comment: This did not work, because the Where clauses were not applied; however you did lead me to find the quickest solution.  products = products.Where(function(r) r.zip = 63039). For whatever reason, I did not think clauses could be appended to the IEnumerable... Thank you

Comment: I think you and I have different idea of what a += operator should do to an enumerable.

Comment: Ran into this issue again on a different project. This is exactly what I needed. At first I had the same problem with your solution (where cause). I added the initial Where clause and it worked like a charm. Ex:   products = products.Concat(repo.Product.Where(function(r) r.Price > 100 AndAlso r.Status = "Open" ))

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic where clause in linq, I normally follow the way mentioned by this [Build Where Clause Dynamically in Linq](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq).

The article is using Expression tree to achieve the dynamic where which is a bit complicated, but the result is elegant in my opinion, and it is written in C#, hope can help you come out with some ideas about it.

Comment: This looks very promising!

Comment: @KRob.Haha, yup, from my point of view, Expression Tree is a fantastic feature provided by .NET regardless of the complexity come with it:)